# jQuery content slider - multiple boxes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a jquery content slider that contains say 3 boxes at one time and you can scroll through to reveal more.

I have tried the jquery plugin repository and google, I have found ones like the Coda Slider, which I've used. Something along those lines but show three boxes of content at once.

I am going to be using it for my latest projects for my portfolio site? Anyone have any they would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: Just came across this after I posted. Thank you for this! Let me check it out.

Comment: I am trying to see if with this, I can tell which one is selected if you click it. When one section is clicked, do function X

Comment: .click(function () { // do something } ;

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

or

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Hey, i am using scrollTo, but how would i get to scroll say a set of three each time?

Answer (score 1):

Smooth Div Scroll would be perfect for this!

http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Since this question shows up in current searches I thought I'd chime in here with something a little more recent: [Revolver.js](https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/revolver)

It's pretty unique among the other sliders out there as it's not an out-of-the-box solution, it's more of a framework to build your slider the way you envisioned it in your mockup. It's a  library for making your own content slider (fully compatible with, but not dependent on, jQuery).

Full Disclosure: I created Revolver.